# Making a public accessor from an inherited protected Java field

Tags: java, scala, inheritance, visibility

How can I make the following work:

```
class Foo extends javax.swing.undo.UndoManager {
  // increase visibility - works for method
  override def editToBeUndone: javax.swing.undo.UndoableEdit = super.editToBeUndone

  // fails for field
  def edits: java.util.Vector[javax.swing.undo.UndoableEdit] = super.edits
}
```

Note that `edits` is a protected field in `CompoundEdit` (a super class of `UndoManager`). I would like to have a public accessor with the same name that reads that field. How would I do that?

```
<console>:8: error: super may be not be used on variable edits
         def edits: java.util.Vector[javax.swing.undo.UndoableEdit] = super.edits
                                                                            ^
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's always reflection.

```
class Foo extends javax.swing.undo.UndoManager {
  def edits(): java.util.Vector[javax.swing.undo.UndoableEdit] =
    classOf[javax.swing.undo.CompoundEdit].
    getDeclaredField("edits").get(this).
    asInstanceOf[java.util.Vector[javax.swing.undo.UndoableEdit]]
}
```

You can also disambiguate the two calls by nesting, though this is ugly:

```
class PreFoo extends javax.swing.undo.UndoManager {
  protected def editz = edits
}
class RealFoo extends PreFoo {
  def edits() = editz
}
```

You do need the `()`, though--without it conflicts with the field itself (and you can't override a `val` with a `def`).

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the visibility of an inherited field, this is not allowed.

*In some case you could 'simulate' such behavior by using composition, but you won't be able to implement the CompoundEdit class obviously.*

Not sure about 'editToBeUndone' as this method doesn't exist in the class:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/CompoundEdit.html

Comment: Sorry, `editToBeUndone` is in `UndoManager` (this is the class I'm actually extending). Anyway. Since I can add a method named `edits`, I just wonder, is there any trick to refer to the field `edits` through some qualification, instead of trying `super.edits`.