# Unable to override java.lang.String field. What is wrong?

Tags: scala, scala-2.9

I tried to compile code that contains

```
class FixedIndexedRepository(override val name: java.lang.String, location: URI) extends FixedIndexedRepo
```

Which extends `FixedIndexedRepo` which extends Java class `AbstractIndexedRepo`

```
public abstract class AbstractIndexedRepo implements RegistryPlugin, Plugin, RemoteRepositoryPlugin, IndexProvider, Repository {
...
protected String name = this.getClass().getName();
...
```

Unfortunately Scala 2.9.2 compiler stops with an error:

```
.../FixedIndexedRepository.scala:29: overriding variable name in class AbstractIndexedRepo of type java.lang.String;
[error]  value name has incompatible type
[error] class FixedIndexedRepository(override val name: java.lang.String, location: URI) extends FixedIndexedRepo
```

How to fix this? What is wrong?

Comment: I'm struggling to reproduce this. Could you provide a section of code that produces this issue in isolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rex says it is ugly:

[Making a public accessor from an inherited protected Java field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591901/making-a-public-accessor-from-an-inherited-protected-java-field)

Given:

```
package j;

public class HasName {
    protected String name = "name";
}
```

then the fake-out is:

```
package user

private[user] class HasNameAdapter extends j.HasName {
  protected def named: String = name
  protected def named_=(s: String) { name = s }
}

class User(n: String = "nom") extends HasNameAdapter {
  def name(): String = named
  def name_=(s: String) { this named_= s }
  this name_= n
}

object Test extends App {
  val u = new User("bob")
  Console println s"user ${u.name()}"
  Console println s"user ${u.name}"
}
```

You were forewarned about the ugly.

I haven't quite worked out the details either, but the weekend is coming up.

> Unfortunately Scala 2.9.2 compiler stops with an error

You mean, *fortunately* it stops with an error.

Comment: Thank you very much. I dind't think about internal mechanism.