# Overriding java public members in scala

Tags: scala, inheritance

When inheriting from a Java class with public members, using scala's `override` modifier raises compilation error like so:

```
Error:(67, 22) overriding variable userId in class Logon of type String;
 value userId has incompatible type
        override val userId = s.user
                     ^
```

The java class looks something along the following lines:

```
public class Logon {
  public String userId = "";
}
```

and the scala code:

```
class MyLogon extends Logon {
  override val userId : String = "abc"
}
```

Removing the modifier results in:

```
Error:(72, 7) overriding variable userId in class Logon of type String;
 value userId needs `override' modifier
  val userId: String = s.user
      ^
```

**Why** is this? Is it a bug? There are related questions e.g. [16607517](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607517/unable-to-override-java-lang-string-field-what-is-wrong) but these seem to be changing the visibility of the fields; that's not the case here - they're all public.

Believe this is with scalac-2.10.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to override public *fields* defined in Java because of how it is implemented in Scala:

A public field (`val user: String`) is represented internally as a combination of private field (say, `private val user$1: String`) and public accessor method (`def user: String = user$1`). It is not allowed to override a *field* with a *method*, thus the compile error.

There is currently no way to omit the public accessor method generation in Scala, so you'll have to find other ways to implement what you want - either by defining a common `trait` or `interface`, or by using another field name, or by wrapping the Java `Logon` into a Scala `Logon` with proper superclass constructs.

Scala interoperates extremely well with Java, but the interop is not perfect, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override member variables.

This should not be confused with how scala allows to override `val` & `var` which works because scala compiler generates getter and setter methods for them.