# How to access a Java inherited field with the same name as a Scala method?

Tags: scala, inheritance, field, scala-java-interop

I'm having a Scala trait `A` with an abstract method

```
trait A[T] {
  def self: T
}
```

Now it happened me that I want to extends a Java class not under my control with a field with the same name:

```
public class B<T> {
    protected T self;
}
```

I'd like to have a class `C` defined like

```
class C[T] extends B[T] with A[T] {
    override def self: T = /* the field `self` of `B` ??? */
}
```

Is it possible to access the field `B.self` somehow so that it doesn't resolve to the method `A.self` instead? Is it even possible to have a scenario like that?

Comment: Duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16618569/1296806 which links to its duplicate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a public accessor from an inherited protected Java field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591901/making-a-public-accessor-from-an-inherited-protected-java-field)